# Android Volley POST request with header and body

Tags: android, post, android-volley

My code is trying to POST data to a server and I need to add a header, I am using the Volley library.

The request works if I do not include the "getparams" method, I am able to post but with no data.

If I include the "getparams" method, the request fails with a 400 (Bad request).

I have not been able to find out where the error is.

```
         public void tryPost() {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    String serverUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/tasks";



    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, serverUrl,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "response = "+ response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Error = "+ error);
        }
    })
    {
        //
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders()  {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return headers;
        }
        ////
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("userId","sargent"); 
            params.put("password","1234567"); 
            return params; //return the parameters
        }
    };
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

For **Authentication** you should include that information inside **getHeaders** instead of **getParams**

Remove getParams and **add** this to your getHeaders

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
       Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();                
       String credentials = "username:password";
       String auth = "Basic "
                        + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
       headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
       headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
       headers.put("Authorization", auth);
       return headers;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The code above adds the headers which works fine, but when combined with the param code, the response is a bad request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use volley much, but I've an alternative which will do your work easily. If you wanna try this out using AsyncHTTPClient.

```
public void tryPost(){
   AsynHTTPClient client = new AsyncHTTPClient();

   //to add the data which you wanna post 
   RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
   params.add("pass your value","from this value");
   params.put("list","your_list"); // this is for passing the arraylist

  client.post(url, params, new AsynchHTTPRespondHandeler(){
  // implement method to get the response from onSuccess()

  });
}
```

For AsynchHTTPClient do this in your gradle :

```
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
```

You can learn more about RequestParams in order to pass different datas [here](https://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/RequestParams.html).

I hope you'll do your work with this. Ping me for any problem.

Comment: How do I add the headers?

Comment: Have you read about the documentation on RequestParams, here you will know how to add these data. Try using request params, this will do your work or else be more precise so that I'd figure out what you want actually ,in here I could figure out that you want to add some data which I've explained already for you.

Comment: I read the doc, which does not explain how to add the headers. Specifically what I want to do is headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

Answer (score 0):

please check this link:

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String s) {
        ///handle response from service
    }, new ErrorResponse() {
      @Override
      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
        //handle error response
      }
  }) {
      @Override
      protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
          Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
          //add params <key,value>
          return params;
      }

      @Override
      public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String,String> headers = Constants.getHeaders(context);
        // add headers <key,value>
        String credentials = USERNAME+":"+PASSWORD;
        String auth = "Basic "
                + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(),
                Base64.NO_WRAP);
        headers.put("Authorization", auth);
        return headers;
      }
  };
 mQueue.add(request);
```

https://gist.github.com/jchernandez/5bec1913af80e2923da8

Answer (score 0):

For POST Requests, for the **Header** part you have to override the **getHeaders()** 'function', and for ** payload/body** of the request you can either provide a **JsonObject** as a parameter to your 'request' or you can override **getParams()** 'function'

**Posting Code For Kotlin Programmers:**

// Creating Json Payload

```
val requestJsonPayloadMap = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
        requestJsonPayloadMap["param1"] = "param1Value"
        requestJsonPayloadMap["param2"] = "param2Value"

        // Creating JSON Object out of the Hash-map
        val requestJSONObject = JSONObject(requestJsonPayloadMap)
```

// Passing the above payload to the request below **[then no need to override the 'getParams()' method]**

```
val volleyEnrollRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(GET_POST_PARAM, TARGET_URL, requestJSONObject,
            Response.Listener {
                // Success Part  
            },

            Response.ErrorListener {
                // Failure Part
            }
        ) {
            // Providing Request Headers

            override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
               // Create HashMap of your Headers as the example provided below

                val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
                headers["app_id"] = APP_ID
                headers["app_key"] = API_KEY

                return headers
            }

            // Either override the below method or pass the payload as parameter above, dont do both 

            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
               // Create HashMap of your params as the example provided below

                val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                headers["param1"] = "param1Value"
                headers["param2"] = "param2Value"
                headers["param3"] = "param3Value"

                return headers
            }
        }
```